# ruby aws sdk ignores logger log level

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-sdk

I am using the ruby AWS SDK to run some scripts, I have set the log level to fatal with this code:

```
$ALOG = Logger.new($stdout)
$ALOG.level = Logger::FATAL
AWS.config( :logger => $ALOG )
```

But I still see this kind of messages when I run the script:

nil
{"content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", "accept-encoding"=>"", "content-length"=>"271", "user-agent"=>"aws-sdk-ruby/1.32.0 ruby/1.9.3 i686-linux"}
nil

Is there something I am missing here. Is this another underlying gem thats is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try AWS.config(:log_level => :fatal)